# Android: Google Maps APIv2 - XML exceeded your daily request

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I have one app which get from the Google server xml, data for Distance and Duration.But today when I test my program she every time crashes.

When I tried to reach the xml from my web browser I get that thing.

```
<DirectionsResponse><status>OVER_QUERY_LIMIT</status><error_message>You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.</error_message></DirectionsResponse>
```

How I exceeded my daily request with couple of tests :D

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=43.21275,27.88652&destination=43.49394,27.41224&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving

I am using this code:

```
public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
```

Everything is back to work.Maybe there are past 24 hours and everything is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked in your api console how many request you made?

Comment: In api console is write this: Google Maps Android API v2 # of requests
28-day total: 115. But in google documentation they say this: daily limit of 100 000 requests per day.

Comment: the key for opening google maps using browser is different. did you used the key of your app?

Comment: are you seeing any errors in your logcat?

Comment: Everything is back to work.Maybe there are past 24 hours.

Comment: I am happy that you have succesfully resolved your problem. Please provide an answer suggesting that waiting 24 hours solved the problems and mark it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
The solution is just to wait 24 hours and everything will back to normal.